# How to reach twitter's Bootstrap installed with npm

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, gulp

I need some help with Gulp. I haven't used Gulp very much, so please forgive me if this is a silly question.

I'm fascinated by the idea of just doing a `npm install bootstrap` in order to get plug-ins etc. for my projects. But I can't seem to figure out how to I'm supposed to access them after the installation.

I want to use Twitter's Bootstrap framework, but as I haven't had the time to teach myself sass yet, so I just want the normal .css files in my project. When I do an `npm install bootstrap` it installs in `./node_modules/bootstrap`. So what is the best way to import just the .css files to my `src/css/` folder while keeping it up to date with `npm update` (if I'd ever want to update it)?

(Obviously doing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">` would be plain wrong?)

I guess I could just add it as a git submodule as an up to date version is available at GitHub - which would accomplish what I'm looking for.

I suppose I'm supposed to do an `import 'bootstrap';` or `require('bootstrap')` but I'm at a loss, so please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just using Gulp on its own, then your best bet would probably be to copy the file to your output directory:

```
gulp.task("bootstrap", function() {
   // This copies the entire folder structure - you could just use one file if you wanted
   gulp.src("./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*")
       .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/bootstrap/"));
});
```

Or concatenate it into your output files using [gulp-concat](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat):

```
var concat = require("gulp-concat");

gulp.task("concat", function() {
    return gulp.src([
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "./src/my-awesome-styles.css"
    ])
    .pipe(concat("style.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Alternatively, if you're using a module bundler like Webpack, you can import it through your JavaScript (assuming you have the [css](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) and [style](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader) loaders installed and configured, or their equivalent in whatever tool you're using):

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the first code snippet worked like a charm! I guess it is best practice to copy it from ``` the node_modules ``` folder so it's always up to date with the rest of the project :)

Comment: @user2267097: I would probably couple that with [gulp-del](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md), so that the `dist` folder gets wiped every time you build. That way you can be sure there's not any old versions of files sitting in there :)

Comment: @user2267097: To clarify, I mean the folder you're outputting to, not Bootstrap's `dist` folder! Comment edit timer expired ):

Comment: True, thanks for the heads up! I've already set it up though :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you just need to call the **relative path** for the bootstrap file and this should take the latest compiled file whenever you receive update through npm update.

I recommend you to go through this to understand about the file stucture: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap

I would **never recommend to use import 'bootstrap';** command.
And, adding **require('bootstrap')** into the Js file which is main entry point for the JS is **same as** having installing packages **locally**.

Note: Node packages follows Semantic Versioning guidelines hence you need not to worry. Just an idea use "**npm install bootstrap --save**" >> this command creates entry into **package.json** file as "dependencies.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Ashok, for your help - I would upvote you, but I'm missing 2 in reputation, haha! :)